# Permission base on the administration menu?

Tags: routes, users, toolbar

I have used [hook_permission](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) to limit user for some places and to created a permission rule. However, I have not combine two permission from another modules for my custom module.

I'm working on a module that would allow user to used the [Administration Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) when user are on a Desktop and used the  [Mobile Friendly Navigation Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/navbar) when the user is on a mobile.

I'm using the [hook_page_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) to hide the css from mobile or desktop display.

So now I'm trying to limited the hook_page_build to user that only have access to the Administration Menu and the Mobile Friendly Navigation Toolbar.

To be more specific here is the permission that I want user to have enable before this module is been load.

Access administration menu

[image]

And the another permission that user need to have is  Use the administration navbar.

[image]

Once these two permission have been granted the my custom module is going to be able load. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here is how is done....

```
function my_custom_module_page_build(&$page) {

    // Check if user have access to the administration menu
    if (!user_access('access administration menu')) return false;

    // Check if user have access to navbar.
    if (!user_access('access navbar')) return false;

     drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_custom_module') . '/css/mobile.css');

}
```